# Lookup values by finding corresponding date between two-column range in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a column to df1 below by searching for the row where Date falls between From and To in df2 and then returning the corresponding values in ISIN. Can anyone help me with this? I am struggling!

Thanks!

df1:

```
    Event_Type  Date
3838    NL  2011-11-01
3839    NL  2011-01-25
3840    NL  2011-08-02
3841    NL  2011-01-03
3842    NL  2011-08-03
3843    NL  2011-12-04
3844    NL  2011-04-27
3845    NL  2011-10-05
3846    NL  2011-06-14
3847    NL  2011-06-21
3848    NL  2011-12-07
3849    NL  2011-07-26
3850    NL  2011-09-13
3851    NL  2011-09-27
```

df2:

```
Sov Tenor   Bond    From    To  Bond Name   ISIN    Nom/Inf
DE  10y EI650542 Corp   2011-06-24  2011-08-19  DBR 3 1/4 07/04/21  DE0001135440    Nominal
DE  10y EI785264 Corp   2011-08-26  2011-11-18  DBR 2 1/4 09/04/21  DE0001135457    Nominal
DE  10y EI879238 Corp   2011-11-25  2012-06-04  DBR 2 01/04/22  DE0001135465    Nominal
DE  10y EJ120241 Corp   2012-04-13  2012-08-31  DBR 1 3/4 07/04/22  DE0001135473    Nominal
DE  10y EJ342271 Corp   2012-07-09  2013-11-01  DBR 1 1/2 09/04/22  DE0001135499    Nominal
DE  10y EJ506625 Corp   2013-01-18  2013-05-17  DBR 1 1/2 02/15/23  DE0001102309    Nominal
DE  10y EJ677578 Corp   2013-05-24  2013-06-09  DBR 1 1/2 05/15/23  DE0001102317    Nominal
DE  10y EJ815896 Corp   2013-09-13  2014-01-24  DBR 2 08/15/23  DE0001102325    Nominal
DE  10y EK037802 Corp   2014-01-31  2014-05-16  DBR 1 3/4 02/15/24  DE0001102333    Nominal
DE  10y EK272890 Corp   2014-05-23  2014-05-09  DBR 1 1/2 05/15/24  DE0001102358    Nominal
DE  10y EK469437 Corp   2014-12-09  2015-09-01  DBR 1 08/15/24  DE0001102366    Nominal
DE  10y EK684154 Corp   2015-01-16  2015-10-07  DBR 0 1/2 02/15/25  DE0001102374    Nominal
DE  10y AF205634 Corp   2015-07-17  2016-08-01  DBR 1 08/15/25  DE0001102382    Nominal
DE  10y JV503423 Corp   2016-01-15  2016-08-07  DBR 0 1/2 02/15/26  DE0001102390    Nominal
DE  10y LW743065 Corp   2016-07-15  2017-06-01  DBR 0 08/15/26  DE0001102408    Nominal
DE  10y AL997549 Corp   2017-01-13  2017-07-07  DBR 0 1/4 02/15/27  DE0001102416    Nominal
DE  10y AO223542 Corp   2017-07-14  2018-05-01  DBR 0 1/2 08/15/27  DE0001102424    Nominal
DE  10y AQ584649 Corp   2018-12-01  2018-06-07  DBR 0 1/2 02/15/28  DE0001102440    Nominal
DE  10y AT428688 Corp   2018-07-13  2019-04-01  DBR 0 1/4 08/15/28  DE0001102457    Nominal
DE  10y AW416188 Corp   2019-11-01  2019-05-07  DBR 0 1/4 02/15/29  DE0001102465    Nominal
DE  10y AZ461235 Corp   2019-12-07  2020-03-01  DBR 0 08/15/29  DE0001102473    Nominal
DE  10y ZP220656 Corp   2020-10-01  2020-12-06  DBR 0 02/15/30  DE0001102499    Nominal
DE  10y BJ948280 Corp   2020-06-19  2021-01-01  DBR 0 08/15/30  DE0001102507    Nominal
DE  10y BN261261 Corp   2021-08-01  2021-11-06  DBR 0 02/15/31  DE0001102531    Nominal
DE  10y BP980366 Corp   2021-06-18  2021-09-17  DBR 0 08/15/31  DE0001102564    Nominal
```

Comment: What have you tried ?  Any codes coming out, even not working ?

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df3 = pd.merge(df.assign(j = 1),df2.assign(j = 1))
df3.loc[df3['Date'].between(df3['From'],df3['To'])]
```